# Upsert - php mongodb- Can't insert a new record

Tags: php, mongodb, upsert

I'm running the following code. if the record already exists it overrides the existing fields with the new one at $updated_fields_array. But if the record doesn't exist I don't know how to add a new record with new fields ($new_fields_array). which operator should I use? Can someone help me out?

```
    $current_time = time();
    $current_mongo_date = new MongoDate($current_time);

    $collection = $this->mongo->selectCollection(MONGO_NOTIFY_DB, 'AccountSettings');

    $criteria_array=array("email" => $email, "name" => $name);

    $updated_fields_array = array (
        'last_sent' => $current_time,
        'updated' => $current_mongo_date
    );

    $new_fields_array = array (
        'created' => $current_mongo_date,
        'updated' => $current_mongo_date,
        'email' => $email,
        'name' => $name,
        'last_sent' => $current_time,
        'deleted' => FALSE
    );

    try {

        $collection->update(
            $criteria_array,
            array('$set' => $updated_fields_array),
            array("upsert" => true)
        );

    } catch (MongoCursorException $mce) {
        log_message('error', 'QUERY UPDATE FAILED :: AccountSettings :: ' . print_r($updated_fields_array, true) . ' :: ' . $mce->getMessage());
    }
    return;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Evgeny's Answer is ok but you are missing one problem

You have duplicate keys in the `updated_fields_array` and `new_fields_array` which throws `MongoDB WriteException` because Mongo will first create the new object and only then update it.

so change

```
$updated_fields_array = array (
    'last_sent' => $current_time,
    'updated' => $current_mongo_date
);

$new_fields_array = array (
    'created' => $current_mongo_date,
    'updated' => $current_mongo_date,
    'email' => $email,
    'name' => $name,
    'last_sent' => $current_time,
    'deleted' => FALSE
);
```

to

```
$updated_fields_array = array (
    'last_sent' => $current_time,
    'updated' => $current_mongo_date
);

$new_fields_array = array (
    'created' => $current_mongo_date,
    'email' => $email,
    'name' => $name,
    'deleted' => FALSE
);
```

and change the query (as Evgeny wrote or the [Documentation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/setOnInsert/))

```
$collection->update(
        $criteria_array,
        array('$set' => $updated_fields_array, '$setOnInsert'=> $new_fields_array),
        array("upsert" => true)
);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use UPDATE command with upsert option and $set/$setOnInsert operators (see https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/setOnInsert/). See example below (note, that you should have unique index on {email:1,name:1})

```
 $current_time = time();
 $current_mongo_date = new MongoDate($current_time);

 $collection = $this->mongo->selectCollection(MONGO_NOTIFY_DB, 'AccountSettings');

$criteria_array=array("email" => $email, "name" => $name);

$updated_fields_array = array (
    'last_sent' => $current_time,
    'updated' => $current_mongo_date
);

$new_fields_array = array (
    'created' => $current_mongo_date,
    'deleted' => FALSE
);

try {

    $collection->update(
        $criteria_array,
        array('$set' => $updated_fields_array, '$setOnInsert'=> $new_fields_array),
        array("upsert" => true)
    );

} catch (MongoCursorException $mce) {
    log_message('error', 'QUERY UPDATE FAILED :: AccountSettings :: ' . print_r($updated_fields_array, true) . ' :: ' . $mce->getMessage());
}
return;
```

Comment: @YannaGenkin How exactly it doesn't work - no document inserted os some fields are missing or wrong?

Comment: Unfortunately, no document is inserted.

Comment: Do you have any specific constraints on the collection such as unique indexes or document validation that could prevent inserting new documents?

Comment: no, I don’t have such definitions in mapping yml files.

Comment: Do you have access to mongodb shell where you could check indexes with `db.AccountSettings.getIndexes()`, see collection constraints with `db.getCollectionInfos()` and try to upsert a sample document with `db.AccountSettings.update`?

Answer (score 1):

I had to use **updateOne**

```
$result = $collection->updateOne(
        array('first_id' => 123456,'some_number' => 333333),
        array('$set' => array('some_status' => 'Delayed')),
        array('upsert' => true)
);
```